# How to create persian calender in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to create persian calender control in asp.net?
 I want to make a persian calender that is able to set note or tryst , in a A particular day in calender. I want get notes from database.

please help me.....

Comment: HAe you tried learning programming? The question is seriously broad as well as totally extremely low level and implies you never did any programming at all and are not to be bothered with documentation or - ouch - tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot give you the best or the perfect answer, but here is what I think might help you!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.persiancalendar(v=vs.110).aspx (PersianCalender Class; link on MSDN)

Go there and learn how to use this class, it will represent the Persian Calender in your website.

Second and the last thing would be to use the elements that are shown to the user and save the date of the meetings or whatso ever you want to be done. Everything related an event would be saved in the Database, then depending on the Date give some special effects to that particular date using CSS or JS.